# How to find a column with respect to another column in the same table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table

- quizId is the ID of a quiz in the db
- userId corresponds to the user who took up the quiz with the respective quizId

  ```
  quizId | userId 
    1    |   9
    1    |   10
    1    |   11
    2    |   11
    3    |   11
  ```
- Now, consider the userId to be 9.
- I need a query that will return only the quizId's 2 and 3
- Meaning, since quizId 1 is taken by userId 9, I don't want them again.

The idea is:

- In the quiz application that I'm making, a person can take a quiz only once.
- There is a page where he can see the list of available quizzes.
- So I want to show only the quizzes which he have not taken already.
- The table above is a quizLog table where the quizId and userId who took up that quiz are stored

I'm sorry but this is the best way I could explain. I hope someone could help understand and help me out. And I couldn't make sure if this is a duplicate question since I have no clue what keywords I should search for. Sorry if this is a duplicate.

**EDIT:**

- I've a table called 'quiz' where quiz details are stored
- I've a table called 'users' where user details are stored
- The table above is called 'quizLog'

This is my existing query

```
    SELECT quiz.quizId,quiz.title
    FROM quiz
    JOIN quizlog
        ON quiz.quizId = quizlog.quizId
    WHERE condition
```

Comment: this should be solvable by a subquery `... WHERE NOT EXISTS ( subquery WHERE userId = yourvalue )` - have a look here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

Comment: You need a separate table of quizzes, so that you can identify the quizzes that no-one has taken yet.  `SELECT q.QuizID FROM QuizList AS q WHERE q.QuizId NOT IN (SELECT T.QuizID FROM QuizzesTaken AS T WHERE T.UserID = 9);`  should work — it may not be the most efficient way to do it.  Your existing design only allows you to identify quizzes that at least one user has taken but your specified user has not taken — and you have to work to do that correctly. Also, please remember to give every table a name — it is infuriating how often people (_not_ just you) forget to give their tables names!

Comment: I'm sorry about that. I have a table named 'quiz' where the quiz details are stored and 'users' where user details are stored. And this table is 'quizLog' where details of quiz and users who took up quizzes are stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest to understand query is:

```
select *
from quiz
where id not in (
  select quiz_id
  from user_quiz
  where user_id = 9)
```

A more advanced way would be:

```
select *
from quiz q
left join user_quiz uq
   on uq.quiz_id = q.id
   and uq.user_id = 9
where uq.user_id is null
```

The join version may perform better on most databases.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to use the table where the quizes are stored. If you take the quizId from the quizLog table, you will only see the ones that someone already have taken, so new quizes would never show up.

You can make a left join on the quizLog table, and get the quizes where there is no match.

```
select q.quizId
from quiz q
left join quizLog l on l.quizId = q.quizId and l.userId = 9
where l.quizId is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Declare @UserID=9

select quizId  from quiz as q1
where quizId not in (
  select quizId from quiz  as q2 
  where userId  = @UserID)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a query that will return the list of question the user didn't take. You will have to write the following query.

`SELECT quizId,title

    FROM quiz
    WHERE quizId NOT IN

    (
    SELECT quizId
    FROM quizLog
    WHERE userId = '9'
    );`
The idea is that when you you use the join in the first query, you will get only quizes that are in quizLog that a user did not do. This means if there ten quizes in quiz table and there are 3 quizes in quizlog , by the time we know that user number 9 as userId, you will get that he didn't do 2 and 3 only. So avoid the join in first SELECT. Thus it can be used in second SELECT.